# Why the metaclass' s __new__ is called

Tags: python, metaclass

Use Python metaclass `A` to create a new class `B`.

When `C` inherit from `B` why `A`'s `__new__`  method is called?

```py
class A(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print(" call A.__new__  ")
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


B = A("B", (), {})


class C(B):
    pass
```

```sh
python test.py 
call A.__new__  
call A.__new__
```

Comment: C is an instance of A, just as B is an instance of A.

Comment: Why did you expect `A.__new__` *wouldn't* be called? `B` is created from `A`, rather than the standard `type`, and `C` inherits `B`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What i confuse is C is not a subclass of A.

Comment: No, but it's a subclass of something whose *metaclass* is `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are instances of Metaclasses, and the default Metaclass `type` is derived from `object`. Metaclasses thus follow the regular rules of creating instances of `object` - `__new__` constructs the instance, `__init__` may initialise it.

```
>>> class DemoClass(object):
...     def __new__(cls):
...         print('__new__ object of DemoClass')
...         return super().__new__(cls)
...
...     def __init__(self):
...         print('__init__ object of DemoClass')
...         return super().__init__()
...
>>> demo_instance = DemoClass()  # instantiate DemoClass
__new__ object of DemoClass
__init__ object of DemoClass
```

The same happens when our class is a metaclass - it is still an `object` and behaves as such.

```
>>> class DemoType(type):
...     def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
...         print('__new__ object %r of DemoType' % name)
...         return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
...
...     def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
...         print('__init__ object %r of DemoType' % name)
...         return super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)
...
>>> demo_class = DemoType('demo_class', (), {})  # instantiate DemoType
__new__ object 'demo_class' of DemoType
__init__ object 'demo_class' of DemoType
```

To reiterate, if `a` is an instance of `A`, then `A.__new__` was used to create `a`. The same applies to classes and metaclasses, since the former are instances of the latter.

A class does not inherit `__new__` from its metaclass. A class *has* a metaclass, and the metaclass' `__new__` is used to create the class.

---

When inheriting from a class (an instance of a metaclass), the metaclass is inherited as well. This means a subclass is *also* an instance of the metaclass. Accordingly, both `__new__` and `__init__` of the metaclass are used to construct and initialise this instance.

```
>>> class DemoClass(metaclass=DemoType):
...     ...
...
>>> class DemoSubClass(DemoClass):
...     ...
...
__new__ object 'DemoClass' of DemoType
__init__ object 'DemoClass' of DemoType
__new__ object 'DemoSubClass' of DemoType
__init__ object 'DemoSubClass' of DemoType
>>> type(DemoClass)  # classes are instances of their metaclass
__main__.DemoType
>>> type(DemoSubClass)  # subclasses inherit metaclasses from base classes
__main__.DemoType
```

The purpose of this is that MetaClasses exist to [define how classes are created](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). This includes subclasses. Calling `__new__` for every subclass allows the metaclass to react to the new class body, additional bases and namespace, and keywords.

Comment: `type` is of type `type`, actually.

Comment: It is both. Both ``object`` and ``type`` are instances of both ``object`` and ``type``. ``isinstance(type, object) == isinstance(type, type) == isinstance(object, type)``. But you are correct that the class of ``type`` is ``type`` itself.

Comment: Yup, I meant that in the sense of `type(type)`.

Comment: @gmds You are right that this is confusing. I've changed the wording a bit, hope that is less misleading.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Good answers